# How to add buttons to a grid WP8.1 MVVM Light?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having trouble building a dashboard in WP8.1.
I'm using the MVVM Light toolkit.

I'm looking after this outcome:
[screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPWHt.png)

I can currently build a dashboard but only with one object per row.

I've searched a lot but haven't found anything to get the desired effect.

Here's the code of the dashboard done programatically:

```
int i = 0;

Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
for (int ct = 0; ct < 3; ct++)
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Name = "stackPanel";
stackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Windows.UI.Color());

foreach (var flow in dashboard.DashboardFlows)
{
    if (flow.Flow.IsInstalled)
    {
        //if next object should change line
        if (i == 3)
        {
            stackPanel.Children.Add(grid);

            grid = new Grid();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int ct = 0; ct < 3; ct++)
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

            i = 0;
        }

        Button button = new Button();
        if (flow.Flow.Type.Equals("COMPNEWS"))
        {
            button.Click += delegate { Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewsPage), flow); };
        }

        //button stackpanel
        StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();

        //Button image
        Image buttonImage = new Image();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(flow.Flow.IconUrl) || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(flow.Flow.IconUrl))
            buttonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(flow.Flow.IconUrl));
        buttonImage.Height = 45;
        buttonImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        stack.Children.Add(buttonImage);

        //Button name
        TextBlock buttonName = new TextBlock();
        buttonName.Text = flow.Flow.Name;
        buttonName.FontSize = 12;
        buttonName.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        stack.Children.Add(buttonName);

        button.Content = stack;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
        button.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
        button.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(130, 30, 30, 30));
        grid.Children.Add(button);

        i++;

    }
}
scroll.Content = stackPanel;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this code related to MVVM? There is nothing MVVM about it

Comment: This is the code I've done to get the desired effect. Now I'm trying to implement this in a MVVM pattern. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Did you try using the UniversalWrapPanel https://github.com/gregstoll/UniversalWrapPanel ? Dunno if it works for UWP Apps though, it's an alternative to the `WrapPanel`which isn't supported in WSA. However, beware that it may not support virtualizations

Comment: You need to research the mvvm pattern.  Then, you need to learn how it works on the WP8.  Bindings, DataTemplates, etc.

Comment: I understand the basics of it. I'm only having trouble with the layout part. Thank you though.